# By time or On/within time

Tags: prepositions

> To gain reputation among your clients, (a) / you ought to finish (b) /
>   every assignment you undertake (c) / ***within*** the stipulated
>   deadline. (d) / No error (d) / No error (e)

This is question of sentence improvement. 
Answer: Replace *within* with *by*

I dont know the difference? It sounds me correct even with *'within'*. 
Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: deadline is like a cut off, so you have to finish it before the deadline. It's not a period or duration of time. That's why I think within deadline does not make much sense.

Comment: In general I would distinguish "within"/"by" as follows: I would use "within" to refer to being inside a specific but time-dependent time-frame such as "within 5 days", "within the warranty period for this product", etc - and "by" to refer to a specific fixed point in time such as "by Tuesday", "by the deadline stipulated in the contract", etc. This looks like a homework question (?) and I can't make sense of the question as asked, even as a native speaker, so you may want to clarify the Q a bit. Where do (a)-(e) come from?